# apex sharing programmatically

Tags: sharing

I am working on a scenario wherein when a user lookup field is filled an Object_Share record is created so that the lookup user can access the record.

So in the trigger I have a function where a Object_share record is created for each record.

For trigger.update it is understandable that sharedRecord.parentId = lookupuser.id. I am wondering how to fill parentId in case of trigger.insert ,as id would not have been created .

What is the workaround for creating shared record in insert?

Comment: ParentId is Id of the record, it is not lookupuser.id.
and in this case write your trigger on after insert,after update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use After Insert event in the trigger as in After Insert records will have the ID assigned to them.